# WPF Binding common datas from database to a listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid. When I select 3  items in datagrid then I right click and click to SHOW LOCATION button. A new window comes. There is a listview in that new window. Now, I want to bind common LOCATIONS of selected items in the previous window. IF selected items' locations are common then they will appear there,otherwise nothing will appeared. Could you give an idea to organize that??

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), you can share this viewmodel with your datagrid as well as your new Window that pops up.

This way you can bind your listview to the selected items.
First try to do it in one window, to make sure your code works then try to do it on another window.
Can you also give some more information, maybe the code you are using now.

It is also possible to use the [EventAggragator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649187.aspx) to share data between views